# First Order Logic Tableau Multiple Universal Identifiers

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I've been looking into tableau lately and I have come across multiple Universal Identifiers which I am not used to. How do I approach these to validate/invalidate with these identifiers and provide an interpretation that works as a counter-example if invalid? Thank you

$\exists x (p(x)$ AND $q(x)) \rightarrow \exists x$ $ p(x)$ AND $\exists x$ $ q(x)$

$\exists x \forall y$ $r(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x \exists y$ $r(x,y)$

Comment: For the first one, I tried taking out the ∃x but I am unsure if this works. And for the second, I am not sure how to approach the changing Identifiers

Comment: Hint re the second: It's true in a singleton interpretation, but there's a 2-element counterexample: let the universe be $\{0,1\}$, and let $r = \{(0, 0), (0, 1)\}$.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks! I need to show its valid via tableau however not sure how to approach the changing Universal Indentifiers

Comment: You mean "alternating quantifiers". You need to construct a tableau that doesn't close, with the negation of the 2nd sentence at the top. The negation of that sentence is equivalent to: $\exists x \forall y\,r(x,y) \land \exists x \forall y\,\neg r(x,y)$.Let $a$ be such that $\forall y\,r(a,y)$, let $b$ be such that $\forall y\,\neg r(b,y)$.

Comment: How did you get the negated equivalent? Is there a particular set of rules to "alternating quantifiers)? I assume it doesn't close as it is invalid (satisfiable when negated)

Comment: Because $\neg(p\to q)\equiv (p\land\neg q)$, and because $\neg\forall\equiv\exists\neg$ and $\neg\exists\equiv\forall\neg$.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "invalid": most commonly that means it has *no* interpretations. You're right that It's *not valid* — not true in all interpretations. For better and worse, "invalid" doesn't always mean "not valid".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it helped & clarified.

Comment: Sorry quick question. When do we know when to substituted the same value of x, for example 2 a's or when to substitute two different x's, such as a and b in this case.

Comment: Don't be fooled by reuse of the same variable in completely discrete parts of a sentence. The original 2nd sentence is better thought of as $\exists x \forall y\,r(x,y) \to \forall u \exists v\,r(u,v)$, and its negation is equivalent to $\exists x \forall y\,r(x,y) \land \exists u \forall v\,\neg r(u,v)$. Different quantified $x$s and $y$s in separate subformulas have nothing to do with each other. Renaming variables makes it explicit: there's an $x$ such that..., all it $a$; and there's a $u$ such that ___, call it $b$. $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be different elements unless proven otherwise.

Comment: Finally, the reason $a$ and $b$ are assumed distinct is because the converse to your 1st sentence is not valid. The converse can be written $\exists x\, p(x) \land \exists y\, q(y) \to \exists z\, (p(z) \land q(z))$.  ¶ By the way, you don't need to/shouldn't pop in and out of MathJax that frantically. LaTeX has spacers and logical operators. I wrote the above sentence as "\exists x\, p(x) \land \exists y\, q(y) \to \exists z\, (p(z) \land q(z))" enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: To confirm, both sentences are not valid? I do not seem to get closed branches for neither. I will make use of the spaces and logical operators in LaTeX.  Thanks.

Comment: Specifically, in the first sentence $\exists x\, (p(x) \land \, q(x))$ is not logically equivalent to $ \exists x\, p(x) \land \exists x\ q(x)$  so why do we use the same letter substitution in tableau?

Comment: You'd substitute one constant for the bound $x$ of the first formula, but, as mentioned, the two bound $x$'s of the 2nd formula are unrelated, and must be instantiated by different constants.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the help.